# Obtener valor en variable POST de una ventana Modal

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, modal

Que tal, pidiendo su ayuda una vez más.
Estoy haciendo una tabla donde muestro clientes y cada cliente tiene un botón donde muestra sus datos personales, lo estoy haciendo que al momento de dar clic en el botón abra una ventana modal y muestra dicha información lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```js
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="bookId"]').val(bookId);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <form method="POST" action="#" name="form1" class="">
 <h2>Clientes</h2>

 <table class="table">
  <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Código</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>RFC</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php 
 while ($res_c = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res_clientes)) {
?>
    <tbody>
     <td><?php echo $res_c['CIDCLIENTEPROVEEDOR']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $res_c['CRAZONSOCIAL']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $res_c['CRFC']; ?></td>
     <td><p><a data-book-id="<?php echo $res_c['CCODIGOCLIENTE']; ?>" href="#my_modal"  data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Dirección</p></a></td>
    </tbody>
 <?php
}
?>
 </table>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Ventana Modal-->
       <!-- Modal Clientes -->
<div class="modal" id="my_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">
            <input type="text" name="bookId" value=""/>
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" id="bookId" name="bookId" value=""  />
<?php 
    $id_cliente = $_POST['bookId'];
    echo $_POST['bookId']; 

    $sql_domicilios = "SELECT * FROM admDomicilios WHERE CIDDIRECCION = ".$id_cliente;
    $res_domicilios = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql_domicilios);
    $f_d = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res_domicilios);

  ?>
        <p>Estado: </p> 
        <p>Colonia: </p> 
        <p>Calle: </p> 

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </form>
```

Ya me manda el Id del cliente al input text, ahora mi problema es que al momento de hacer $_POST['bookId']; para pasarlo a una variable y hacer condiciones me dice que no se encuentra.. Agradezco mucho su atención y ayuda.

Comment: ¿Dónde usas `$_POST['bookId'];`? Dices que es lo que te da error, pero no aparece en el código compartido

Comment: Lo siento esa parte del código se me pasó mostrarla, como puedes observar una vez que me da el resultado en el input, trato de ahora obtener su valor para hacer una comparación en mi BD y mostrar los resultados.. Gracias!!! @AlvaroMontoro

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo de manera general (considero) tienes lo siguiente en la página cuando se carga.

## Lo que posiblemente tienes

Tu **index.php** (nombre ejemplo):

```
<html>
   <!-- Tus metas,link y demas de inicio/encabezado -->
   <script>
      <!-- en alguna parte declarado; lo coloque aquí -->
      $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
          var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
          $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="bookId"]').val(bookId);
      });
   </script>
<body>
   <!-- Algo antes del modal que armas -->

   <!-- Inicio estrutura de la modal -->
   <div class="modal" id="my_modal">
      <!-- Aqui lo que tienes antes de la sección PHP -->
      <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" id="bookId" name="bookId" value=""  />
          <?php 
              $id_cliente = $_POST['bookId'];
              echo $_POST['bookId']; 
              $sql_domicilios = "SELECT * FROM admDomicilios WHERE CIDDIRECCION = ".$id_cliente;
              $res_domicilios = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql_domicilios);
              $f_d = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res_domicilios);
            ?>
        <p>Estado: </p> 
        <p>Colonia: </p> 
        <p>Calle: </p> 

      </div>
      <!-- Aqui lo que tienes despues de la sección PHP -->
   </div>
   <!-- Fin estrutura de la modal -->

   <!-- Algo despues del modal que armas -->
   <!-- Quizas más código -->
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora va la explicación; si lo tienes asi cuando cargas ese página en particular, tu error es que de un proceso previo no estas pasando via POST ese parámetro.

## Lo que debes hacer (como lo veo)

Estando en la página donde muestras la modal hacer uso de Ajax (no profundizare en ello; asumo lo tienes bien); algo como:

Tu **index.php**:

```
<html>
   <!-- Lo necesario anrtes del "body" -->
<body>
   <!-- Lo necesario antes de la estructura para la modal -->

   <!-- Inicio: contenedor para la modal -->
   <div class="modal" id="my_modal">
   <!-- Mira que no coloco nada -->
   </div>
   <!-- Fin:    contenedor para la modal -->

   <!-- Lo necesario despues de la estructura para la modal -->
</body>
</html>
```

Formando la modal en otro PHP armado en servidor via Ajax; lo nombrare (aqui) **paraModal.php**:

```
<form [todo lo que necesites colocarle]>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">
            <input type="text" name="bookId" value=""/>
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" id="bookId" name="bookId" value="<?= $_POST['bookId']; ?>"  />
<?php 
    $id_cliente = $_POST['bookId'];
    echo $_POST['bookId']; 

    $sql_domicilios = "SELECT * FROM admDomicilios WHERE CIDDIRECCION = ".$id_cliente;
    $res_domicilios = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql_domicilios);
    $f_d = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res_domicilios);

  ?>
        <p>Estado: </p> 
        <p>Colonia: </p> 
        <p>Calle: </p> 

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Entonces** para el momento que se realice el click para mostrar la modal, invoques el Ajax (asegurate de pasar e indicar los parámetros son vía POST) llames a **paraModal.php** y su resultado lo insertes en `id="my_modal"` y concluir con la instrucción que muestra la modal.